# Regex matching and grouping results

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a pre-processor and I have a piece of code needed to get a match.

Example input:

```
padding: eval((20%/2)+5)) eval(30);
width: eval(100%/2);
font-family: font-find("Helvetica");
```

I need to match and group the matches base on the string provided.
Expected output should be:

```
[0] = eval((20%/2)+5)
[1] = eval(30)
[2] = eval(100%/2)
[3] = font-find("Helvetica")
```

The content of the item inside the parenthesis can be any value.
It's easy to match the items for output 2 - 3, but I can't get to group the values for 0 and 1.

I'm writing the code in PHP.
"eval" and "font-find" are arbitrary functions.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Might want to approach this another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+\(\S*\))/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: The \w+ should be [\w-]+ for names with hyphens